# SQL - find all ROUTEMAP_ID in a table which has a foreign key

Tags: sql, select

I'dlike to ask you for help.

I have one table ROUTEMAP_DETAILS with following columns:
ID FLIGHT_LEG ROUTEMAP_ID (this column is a foreign key and is related to the table ROUTEMAP).

The table ROUTEMAP_DETAILS looks like:

```
(ID, FLIGHT_LEG, ROUTEMAP_ID):
(1,  0,         222224444)
(2,  0,          334843444)
(3,  1,          345436456)
(4,  2,          434355666)
(5,  null,       435058395)
```

The table ROUTEMAP_DETAILS can contain many rows with the same ROUTEMAP_ID:

```
(ID, FLIGHT_LEG, ROUTEMAP_ID):
(33, 0,          323232223)
(34, 1,          323232223)
(35, 2,          323232223)
```

My question is: how to find ALL ROUTEMAP_IDs which have FLIGHT_LEG 1 or 2 or 3 or both/all  BUT NO 0? For example I'm looking for this case (I'd like to know if this issue exists in my table):

```
(ID, FLIGHT_LEG, ROUTEMAP_ID):
(34, 1,          323232223)
(35, 2,          323232223)
```

I've tried to group my select by ROUTEMQP_ID but I didn't cope with this unfortunately.

Thank you very much for your help!

Best regards 
Mateusz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated sub-query with NOT EXISTS:

```
select ID, FLIGHT_LEG, ROUTEMAP_ID 
from ROUTEMAP_DETAILS as a
where not exists
(
    select * from ROUTEMAP_DETAILS as b
    where a.ROUTEMAP_ID = b.ROUTEMAP_ID
    and FLIGHT_LEG = 0
)
AND FLIGHT_LEG > 0
```

Comment: meisen99 - this is just what I wanted to achieve - it works perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Do you mind marking this as the correct answer?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id,
       flight_leg,
       routemap_id
  FROM (SELECT *,
               RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY routemap_id ORDER BY id ASC) AS [rank]
          FROM routemap_details
       ) a
 WHERE [rank] > 1
```

Result

```
id  flight_leg  routemap_id
34  1           323232223
35  2           323232223
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT * 
 FROM ROUTEMAP_DETAILS
 WHERE FLIGHT_LEG IN (1, 2, 3)
```

or try in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/73990/2/0)